# Does buffer overflow change data type of variable it is overwriting?

Tags: memory, buffer

Say I have a C character array `char buf[15]`. Say variable `int set_me = 0` has its data stored in a memory location directly after `char buf[15]`. If I overflowed `buf` with string `"aaabbbcccdddeee\xef\xbe\xad\xde"`, would `set_me`'s data type change from an integer to a character array?

Comment: Depends on who is interpreting the data. finally everything is binary. So the way you interpret it, it can be a valid integer value or cause a cast error

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No.

The "data type" of a variable is only relevant in source code (and even then only in some languages). It tells the compiler how to treat the variable.

These high-level data types do not exist as such in compiled (native) code. They can affect what instructions a compiler generates, but the instructions themselves don't care if the data represents a character or a number.

---

Variables do not exist in hardware. In hardware, you have memory locations and the instructions that operate on them.

A variable could be seen as a *view* of the data at a memory location — if you squint and look at the same memory slightly differently (a different variable with different type referring to the same location), the same binary value can have a different meaning.

For example, the byte 0x41 could be interpreted as the UTF-8-encoded character `A`. It could also be interpreted as the single-byte integer `65`. It could also be interpreted as one byte in a multi-byte integer or floating point number, or one byte in a multi-byte character encoding. It could be the bitset `0b1000001`. All from the same byte in the same memory location. In the C language, you can see this effect by *casting* to these different types.

When you have a "buffer overflow", you're doing something outside the bounds of what your compiler or language might expect. But, as far as the hardware is concerned<sup>1</sup>, you are writing bytes (whether single or multiple) to a memory location. A memory location does not have a "type". In fact, the hardware doesn't even know that any particular set of bytes makes an array or buffer in your code.

Wherever you next access that memory location in your code, the instructions will run as originally defined. e.g. if they were expecting a number there, they will act on whatever bytes of data *as if* they were a number.

---

To use your example, assuming your `int` is a signed 4-byte (32-bit) integer:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Source code |                  char[15]                  |    int    |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Memory      |61|61|61|62|62|62|63|63|63|64|64|64|65|65|65|EF|BE|AD|DE|
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see that the `int`'s memory location now contains `0xEFBEADDE`, assuming a big-endian system<sup>2</sup>. This is the signed 32-bit int `-272716322`. Now, if you interpret the same memory as an unsigned int (`uint`), it would be `4022250974` instead. For exactly the same data in memory, the meaning depends entirely on how you view it.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are some mechanisms which prevent you from writing into protected regions of memory, and will crash your program if you attempt to do so.

<sup>2</sup> x86 is actually little-endian, which means you interpret the bytes making up a larger value backwards. So on x86 you would instead have `0xDEADBEEF`, giving signed `-559038737` or unsigned `3735928559`.

Comment: So `0xdeadbeef`, on an x86 architecture, would take up less space in memory than its decimal counterpart, `3735928559`?

Comment: @DarienSpringer Both take up 4 bytes of memory — they are the same 4-byte sequence. They are identical in memory. You could consider it all to be base 2 (binary) in memory, if you want. Then, when you display them (convert to a string for output) you can choose a base to display — the hex is base 16, and the decimal is base 10. The string representations are stored in a different memory location and can use different amounts of memory (as each character is a separate byte). The *string* `0xDEADBEEF` is stored in memory as `0x30 0x78 0x44 0x45 0x41 0x44 0x42 0x45 0x45 0x46`.

Comment: @DarienSpringer Put another way, a number is the same number no matter what base it's in. Hex is a convenient (compact) way to view binary. Physically, it's binary. Humans like decimal, so we more often display numbers as decimal. But until we get to the display step, all numerical operations (add, subtract, multiply, etc.) work on the same binary data in memory.

Comment: _"You can see that the int's memory location is now 0xEFBEADDE"_ Nitpick: I know you didn't intend this, but it sounds like you're saying the int is located _at_ the memory location `0xEFBEADDE`. Perhaps reword that a bit. Otherwise this is a superb answer - I particularly like the "view" analogy and the "squinting" idea :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good point. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

From a C perspective, the answer would be "Who knows? It's Undefined Behavior".

Types are a C concept, not hardware. But the C rules don't apply if your program has Undefined Behavior, that is the literal meaning of Undefined Behavior in the C standard. And buffer overflows are one form of that.

I initially wrote "the C rules no longer apply", but in fact the Undefined Behavior is retroactive. C rules don't apply to a program that will have Undefined Behavior in the future.